# How to comment out comment in Doxygen documentation

Tags: comments, doxygen

I am using Doxygen's `\page`, `\subpage` and `\section` constructions to make overview documentation for my application.  Somewhere in this I am using HTML to create a nicely formatted table.

However, I want to remove a part of the table in the output, without removing the comment itself.  E.g.

```
/*!
\page MAINPAGE Main Page

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Do This</td>
      <td>100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Do That</td>
      <td>200</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Yet another one</td>
      <td>300</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove the line containing 'Do That' without removing the 'text' itself from the file.

If this were simple source code, I could simply comment this out using `//` or `/* */`.

I found out that I could use `\if` or `\latexonly` (we only generate html output) but both seem a workaround (looks like using `if(false)` in code to comment out a block).

Isn't there a clean way to comment out comment in Doxygen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try \cond \endcond tags? It's described here http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdendcond

Comment: Link is dead at the time of this writing.

Comment: @KutalmisB thanks for spotting it. I've updated links using official documentation references.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the part to be excluded within `@cond` and `@endcond` blocks. Like so:

```
@cond DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE
<tr>
    <td>Do That</td>
    <td>200</td>
</tr>
@endcond
```

and ensure that you have not defined `DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE` in any place that doxygen can see. `DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE` is just what I use, it not a special keyword, you can choose any name you prefer.

Comment: Oh, per the convention you follow, that would be `\cond` ... `\endcond`. Mentioning for completeness.

Comment: According to the documentation you can simply use \cond without any string behind it.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, but I still prefer putting something there to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Besides \cond...\endcond you can also use HTML comments, i.e `<!-- this is a comment in a comment -->` inside doxygen comments, as explained at the bottom of this page in the manual http://www.doxygen.org/manual/htmlcmds.html